# How to collapse columns of different heights

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my website, I have 6 columns of images. Each has the same amount of images but because the images are different heights, all the columns have different heights.

This is fine, except when I try to make it responsive. When the screen gets smaller, I collapse the last 3 columns to go beneath the first 3 columns. The columns are floated to the left so I just use

```
clear:left;
```

on the 4th column to achieve this. However, there is a gap between the columns when I do this...

[image]

I need to remove that gap. I want the columns beneath to touch the columns above. How can I achieve this? Can this be done with solely CSS?

The columns have the following...

```
.imageWrap-col {
    float: left;
    max-width: 16%;
}
```

And the column container has `overflow:auto`...

```
#gallery {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to try and use bootstrap's grid system? Might help.

Comment: Have you looked into using a flexbox solution instead? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Winter I am trying to use flex box but it gives me the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try to [column](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) css

```css
body {/* or any container */
  -moz-column-width:180px;
  column-width:180px;
  column-gap:0.2em;
  max-width:800px;/* enough to hold four columns */
  margin:auto;
}
img {
  width:100%;/* or same value as column-width */
}

/* demo purpose */

html:before {
  content:' see snippet in fullpage, then resize window';
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.6em;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x110"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x250"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/350x150"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x110"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x250"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/350x150"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x110"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x250"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/350x150"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x110"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x250"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/350x150"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x110"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x250"/>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/350x150"/>
```

it works in any container with any kind of box :

```css
div {
  -moz-column-width: 200px;
  column-width: 200px;
  column-gap: 0.2em;
}
figure,
img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
figure {
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}
figcaption,
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>see snippet in fullpage, then resize window</h1>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x110" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x250" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/350x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x110" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x110" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x250" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/350x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x250" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/350x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x110" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x250" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/350x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x110" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x250" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/350x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x110" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x250" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/350x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x110" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x250" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/350x150" />
    <figcaption>
      caption text
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```